# What timezone does Ask Ubuntu use?

Tags: discussion

In Ask Ubuntu, there are limits on how many things you can do each day. For example:

- You can only flag 36 items per day,
- You can only review 20 items from one category per day,
- You can only get 200 reputation per day, and
- You can only use 40 votes per day.

As well as opportunities to receive badges within a set time period, like:

[image: enthusiast]
[image: fanatic]
[image: mortarboard and necromancer]
[image: Revival]
[image: suffrage]
[image: vox populi]

Those are all the badges that have a requirement of doing a task in a time frame.

Since Ask Ubuntu is a very vibrant place with many nationalities and cultures, it's quite obvious that **not everyone is in the same time zone**.

So, what time zone does Ask Ubuntu use to determine a 'new day' or a 24-hour period? Do they use a clock at all, or do they measure the time in your time zone and count on another 24 hours?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple answer to that is UTC.

All of the daily events, such as the reset of your daily rep limit, occur at midnight universal time.

Comment: Oh... I had hoped it went on a true "X number of Y per day" basis. e.g., as long the last of 40 votes was within 24h of the first, you'd get Vox Populi.